# Why can I not login with one user but with another user using ssh-keys?

Tags: 13.04, ssh

I don't get it:

Why can I not login via ssh public-key beside the fact that I only copied the successful used private key from a user account on the client side to the root account on the client side?

I checked permissions in root on the client side authorized keys are there via ssh-copy-id.

Regards

Comment: It is not clear what do you want. You have server A and B. You copy ssh key from one server A to B? You want generate new ssh-key for B? Do you have access by ssh-key to server A?

Comment: Server A with USER using the private key to reach server B successfully. Copying the keys from USER to ROOT account on server A can't reach server B.

I found the solution myself. I forgot to use ssh-add/ssh-agent with my ROOT account on server A. Beside this fact I now use the much more easy to use KEYCHAIN package to solve this. Thank you c0rp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to use ssh-add/ssh-agent with my ROOT account on server A. :-/

Beside this fact I now use the much more easy to use KEYCHAIN package to solve this problem. Highly recommended!